# Where should I modify?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is an oracle sql.
SQL servel says  "there is no USERS Table"
but user table exists in my db.

```
MERGE INTO USERS
USING DUAL
ON (id='001')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET no='002' ,from_date = TO_DATE('20-07-01 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT USERS (id,no,from_date) VALUES ('02','t002',TO_DATE('20-07-01 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the table name.

```
MERGE INTO USERS
USING DUAL
ON (id='001')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET no='002' ,from_date = TO_DATE('20-07-01 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (id,no,from_date) VALUES ('02','t002',TO_DATE('20-07-01 00:00:00', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```